# How to collect the form tag html attributes in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form tag as mentioned below in the SaveResults.cshtml page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new
{
    Id = "ABC",
    Name = "Test",
    SSN = "1234567"
}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="title">
                    Title
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="title" name="title">
                    <option>Mr</option>
                    <option>Dr</option>
                    <option>Ms</option>
                    <option>Mrs</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="givenName">
                    Given Name
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="name" name="givenName" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="surname">
                    Surname
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}

<div id="result"></div>
```

I want to collect the ID, Name and SSN in jquery POST method to pass it to an action method. I tried with the below but it is not working.

```
$(function () {
           $("form").submit(function (e) {
                $.post($(this).attr("action"), { id: this.Id, name: this.Name, ssn: this.SSN})
                    .done(function (response) {
                        $("#result").html(response);
                });
                e.preventDefault();
           });
        });
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: `SSN` is not a valid attribute for the `form` tag. Instead use `data-` attributes - `new { data-id="ABC", data-name="Test", data-ssn="1234567" }` and to extract them - `{ id: $(this).data('Id'), name: $(this).data('name), ssn: $(this).data('ssn') }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those values into hidden fields in your form:

```
@Html.Hidden("Id", Id)
@Html.Hidden("Name", Name)
@Html.Hidden("SSN", SSN)
```